# Power BI : Showing image in slicer visual

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have been following [this link](https://www.blue-granite.com/blog/simple-steps-to-embed-images-in-power-bi) to show images in visuals. Currently, it works for table visual (converting image into **base64** text and modelling the column as **Image URL** format). However, I like to show image in **Slicer visual**.

Idea is to show image in Slicer to filter data in Matrix visual data which are available on same page. I have achieved to filter matrix visual by showing data as ***List view & Horizontal Orientation*** in slicer visual. But how to show image in slicer visual?

Any idea or clue are highly appreciated.

Comment: The standard slicer doesn't support images in the filter experience. The 3rd Party Chiclet slicer does, but only via url

Comment: Great., This looks matching to my requirement.! :-) In Chiclet slicer I can make use to base64 Image URL also...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard Power BI slicer doesn't support images to enable selection by that method. The 3rd party [Chiclet Slicer](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/WA104380756?tab=Overview) does. It will support it via direct url, or you can wrap the base 64 image in a url(ish) for example.

```
<img src=”data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4QuLRXhpZgAATU………r3v3Xuve/de697917r//Z”/>
```